# Import TransferOrder lines (InventTransferLine)

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am trying to import a transfer order line with this code from [Transfer Orders Import](http://ax2012xppdataimport.blogspot.ro/2013/12/microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-xpp-transfer.html):

```
InventDim inventDim;
InventTransferLine inventTransferLine;
#define.ShipDate("1/1/2016")
#define.ReceiveDate("1/1/2016")

//Order line
inventDim.clear();
inventDim.InventSiteId = "GENERAL";
inventDim.InventLocationId = "103";

inventTransferLine.clear();
inventTransferLine.initValue();

inventTransferLine.ItemId = "A01103472";
inventTransferLine.InventDimId = InventDim::findOrCreate(inventDim).inventDimId;
inventTransferLine.QtyTransfer = 2;

inventTransferLine.initFromInventTableModule(InventTableModule::find(inventTransferLine.ItemId,ModuleInventPurchSales::Invent));

inventTransferLine.QtyRemainReceive = inventTransferLine.QtyTransfer;
inventTransferLine.QtyRemainShip = inventTransferLine.QtyTransfer;

inventTransferLine.ShipDate = str2Date(#ShipDate, 213);
inventTransferLine.ReceiveDate = str2Date(#ReceiveDate, 213);

inventTransferLine.initFromInventTransferTable(inventTransferTable, false);
inventTransferLine.LineNum = InventTransferLine::lastLineNum(inventTransferLine.TransferId) + 1.0;

if (inventTransferLine.validateWrite())
{
    inventTransferLine.insert();
}
else
    throw error("Order line");
```

Is this the correct or the preferred way to do it?

What's the use of inventDim here? I am transferring this product from warehouse A to warehouse B and those are specified in the selected header, meaning the InventTransferTable record.

And i am not sure about these two lines:

```
1. inventTransferLine.QtyRemainReceive = inventTransferLine.QtyTransfer;
2. inventTransferLine.QtyRemainShip = inventTransferLine.QtyTransfer;
```

RemainReceive from where? i can't figure out what are they referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are more or less good to go.
You seems to have [copied what others have done](http://ax2012xppdataimport.blogspot.dk/2013/12/microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-xpp-transfer.html), which is good.

There are other ways to it, one using `AxInventTransferTable` and `...Line` classes, another using the `TransferOrderCreateService` service. None will give you much competitive advantage, if working from within AX.

The `InventDim` (see [white paper](https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/E/3/4E36B655-568E-4D4A-B161-152B28BAAF30/Implementing_Item-Product_data_management_framework_for_Microsoft_Dynamics_AX_2012_Applications_AX2012.pdf)) contains the inventory, storage, and tracking dimensions of the item. You will need to set more fields if the item requires it as specified on the item and product.

- Product dimensions. Item dimensions, color, size and configuration.
- Storage dimensions. These are Site, Warehouse, Location, and Pallet.
- Tracking dimensions. These are Batch number and Serial number.

A shipment is a two-step thing. First you ship the item from the source site/warehouse. Later you receive the item at the target site/warehouse.
The `QtyRemainShip`and `QtyRemainReceive` fields represents the quantity remaining for each step.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jan. Regarding the InventDim, should it be set to the "From warehouse" value taken from the selected header ? I think it should but it's worth to ask in order to be sure.

Comment: I think so too, but you can answer that yourself by creating a line using the user interface.

Comment: In initFromInventTransferTable i found this line : this.InventDimId   = this.inventDimMergeWarehouse(_inventTransferTable.InventLocationIdFrom,_inventTransferTable).InventDimId; So i think setting those dimensions is redundant. And indeed, it sets the location to the "From warehouse" value.